# Website Operating System desktop layout

Tags: layout, web, operating-system

I'm going to develop a application in the company I work for, and I were asked to create a layout as an OS desktop, with applications, icons, shortcut and everything.
I've tried searching so far, but found nothing. My real problem is that I don't know what to search, I don't have a definition for what I need.

To understand butter, it's something like AirDroid or Glide OS (but no, i'm not using any flash).

Thanks :)

**Edit**

If someone is curious about this, I found this library:
http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/

It was made exactly for what I need. :)

Comment: Some years ago, I see some windowing solution for web with the Rich Ajax Platform (http://www.eclipse.org/rap/demos/), but I think, this is not exactly you want.

Comment: Are you looking for something that replace the standard desktop? e.g.: Windows desktop, Start Menu, Taskbar, etc. If so, then you're looking for a desktop shell replacement. For linux, this would be a replacement for KDE or Gnome.

Comment: HTML(5) + CSS + JavaScript will do the trick.

Comment: is the aim to run it from the desktop or inside a browser? will it be offline - local only to a user's machine or running across a local network or on an intranet or on the internet? you say it needs shortcuts - shortcuts to local applications or web applications?